# Usage of OpenPGP within a browser and without Node.js

Tags: javascript, openpgp

Is it possible to use OpenPGP.js without node.js? From the Abstract (https://openpgpjs.org/) I would expect that it is sufficient to have the package (openpgpjs-master.zip), an appropriate browser (e.g. Firefox) and a minimalisitic index.html. Is this true? And does anybody have a an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenPGP in browser, more information about compability:
https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs

Download (minified) js files:
https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/tree/master/dist